# Dynamics 365 - create case from unknown email

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

My customer has requirement like below:

Generally he would like to achieve an action - when a person, who isn't registered in Dynamics 365 as a contact send an email to Dynamics 365 queue, it should create a new contact and a new case based on the email.

Actually creating cases for existing contacts works fine, but it doesn't work for email address which aren't associated with any contact.

The queue has enabled option "Create records for email from unknown senders" and I have created a creation and update rule, which should create a case as below:

[image: Url for attachment available below]

[image: Url for attachment available below]

As I described earlier - it doesn't.

In background sessions of email there is an error related with this creation and update rule:

[image: Url for attachment available below]

Do you know how should I configure rules, to allow Dynamics 365 creating case for email addresses which isn't associated with any contact?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing a small configuration. From [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customer-service/automatically-create-case-from-email#create-cases-automatically-using-rules) it appears that the below 2 settings go hand in hand. Set the case creation rule owner’s personal options also & test.

> **Create cases for email from unknown senders.** If you select this check box, all email messages from unknown senders (a sender whose email address is not present in any Dynamics 365 records) are converted to cases. A contact record is also created for this unknown sender.
>
> This option, in conjunction with the **Automatically create records in Microsoft Dynamics 365** option in the rule owner’s Personal Options, determines whether a case and contact record is created (see [Set personal options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/basics/set-personal-options))